# preinstall VScode remote extensions in a docker container

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code

I'm currently using the vscode extension to attach to running containers in Kubernetes as described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container.

When attaching vscode will install some extensions in the remote container - this works reliably, but it quite slow.

Is it possible to figure out how to install these extensions into the base image so that remote connection can happen quickly?

Thanks